# Find the general solution to the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I would like to find the general solution to the ODE:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{2x}{1+x^2}y=\frac{(1+x^2)^3(4x+1)}{4-x}y^5$$

and the tips given is "let $z:=\frac{1}{y^4}$. What is the differential equation that z satisfies?"

I tried by sub $$z=\frac{1}{y^4}$$ $$dz=-\frac{4}{y^5}dy$$

but the equation doesn't seem familiar to me. May I know how should I proceed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{2x}{1+x^2}y=\frac{(1+x^2)^3(4x+1)}{4-x}y^5$$
$$(1+x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}+{2x}y=\frac{(1+x^2)^4(4x+1)}{4-x}y^5$$
$$((1+x^2)y)'=\frac{(1+x^2)^4(4x+1)}{4-x}y^5$$
Try to separate now.
$$\dfrac {((1+x^2)y)'}{(y(1+x^2))^5}=\frac{(4x+1)}{(4-x)(1+x^2)}$$
Integrate both sides.
$$\int \dfrac {d(y(1+x^2))}{(y(1+x^2))^5}=\int \frac{(4x+1)}{(4-x)(1+x^2)} \, dx$$

Comment: Thanks! However, I got stuck after doing integration $$y^4=-\frac{4}{(1+x^2)^4}ln(\frac{\sqrt(1+x^2)}{4-x})+C$$ May I know how can I obtain $y$ as the subject, or have I did something wrong during the integration? thanks!

Comment: When you have $y^4=f(x)$ then $y= \pm \sqrt[4] {f(x)}$   @enginew

Comment: And you also have two more complex solutions.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by 2 more complex solutions? I thought $y=\pm \sqrt[4]{f(x)}$ 
is all I have for the final general solution as derived from $y^4=f(x)$ . Thanks!

Comment: You also have that $y=\pm i \sqrt {f(x)}$ as solutions @enginew. So it makes four solutions since you have $y^4$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Multiply both sides by $1 + x^{2}$ in order to obtain
\begin{align*}
(1+x^{2})y' + 2xy = \frac{(1+x^{2})^{4}(4x+1)}{4-x}y^{5} \Longleftrightarrow ((1+x^{2})y)' = \frac{4x+1}{(1+x^{2})(4-x)}((1+x^{2})y)^{5}
\end{align*}

Then make the substitution $u = (1+x^{2})y$ in order to obtain the following ODE
\begin{align*}
u' = \frac{(4x+1)u^{5}}{(1+x^{2})(4-x)}
\end{align*}
which is separable.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you! but after replacing $u$ with $(1+x^2)y$ after integration, i got $$y^4=-\frac{4}{(1+x^2)^4}ln(\frac{\sqrt(1+x^2)}{4-x})+C$$ which seems is not the final form of the general solution. Should I further make LHS as $y$? thank you!